# How to clone Discourse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, clone

I want to learn Rails by cloning some popular open-source projects in Github (for example: http://github.com/discourse/discourse). However, the its code is massive, so I don't know how to start. Can you give me some advices to clone it with core feature ? And can you show me ways to learn from open source project

Until now, I read some Rails book such Agile Web Development With Rails The Rails 4 ways, etc and build some real websites. So, I think I am better than newbie

Thank you very much !

Comment: What do you mean, clone? Reimplement?

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion-based. And my opinon (duh :)) is that it might be better to start with less massive project as you risk spending more time figuring out the overall structure that actually learning something.

Comment: Also, Discourse is **not** a Rails app. It's an Ember app with rails for api backend. Big difference!

Comment: This piece is too big for you to chew. Choose another. Implement a blog engine, perhaps. I heard it's easy with rails :)

Comment: Thank you everybody. I will choose smaller project